# Replacement of for loop to filter values from data frame with multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two lists: list1 and list2, and one data frame: df1. I am using some filter to append some from_account values to empty list p.

few values of list1=[128195, 101643, 143865,  59455, 108778,  66042, 138456,  66043]

and few values of list2=[128594, 128599, 128596, 128588, 128168, 125410, 127166, 127078]

```
p=[]
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        ss=df1[df1.to_account==i]
        for k in range(0,len(ss.from_account)):
            if(ss.from_account.values[k]==j):
                p.append(j)
```

Using for loop it's taking huge execution time, is there any alternatives to do it that gives same result but least execution time.

Comment: Most questions should have some sort of minimal stub of data so that we can run and play with your code and make sure we have the correct output. Don't dump all of your data here, but what do one or two elements of `list1`, `list2`, and so on look like? I.e., can you adjust the question so that we could run it locally and examine `p` without any additional guessing as to what your data looks like?

Comment: For performance questions, it is also extremely helpful to know things like the **sizes** of the objects in questions. If those sizes are huge enough, it's important to know some basic hardware specs too (like how much RAM you have). The appropriate choice of algorithm usually depends on how big the inputs are.

Comment: One thing to save time could be already to put `ss=df1[df1.to_account==i]` out of the j-loop one step higher into the i-loop, as it does not depend on j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `ss.from_account.values` is a list, so instead of looping through it with variable `k`, you can just check whether the value is in that list:

```
p=[]
for i in list1:
    ss=df1[df1.to_account==i]
    for j in list2:
        if j in ss.from_account.values:
            p.append(j)
```

I furthermore moved the declaration of `ss` outside the second loop, so you only that once. I think you could even optimize it further:

```
p=[]
for i in list1:
    ss=df1[df1.to_account==i]
    p += [j for j in list2 if j in ss.from_account.values]
```